# where is exchange.pancakeswap.finance repo located?

Tags: ethereumjs, uniswap, pancakeswap

[image]

I have forked pancake frontend successfully from here: https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-frontend

But seems like Trade(swap, liquidity ...etc) are hosted from different code. Where can i find this? I would like to fork this just like frontend code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the exchange feature in https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-interface-v1.